# get_signing_key_from_jwt throws error Unable to find a signing key that matches kid

Tags: python, jwt, jwk

I'm seeing this error when getting the signing key:

> PyJWKClientError: Unable to find a signing key that matches: "{kid}"

The signing_key is where I'm seeing the error:

```
import jwt

jwks_uri="https://my_auth_server/oauth2/v1/keys"
jwks_client = jwt.PyJWKClient(jwks_uri)

signing_key = jwks_client.get_signing_key_from_jwt(token['access_token'])
```

I'm getting the token like this:

```
tdata = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri': config['redirect_uri'],
            'client_id': config['client_id'],
            'client_secret': config['client_secret'],
            'scope': 'openid',
            'state': state,
            'code': code,
        }
         ret = requests.post(config["token_endpoint"], headers=theaders, data=urlencode(tdata).encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: I understand the error message to mean that in the URL no key with a kid can be found that corresponds to the kid specified in the token. Have you checked whether the kids are consistent?

Comment: @Topaco - hello! what do you mean by 'whether the kids are consistent?' as in do they change? if so, yes the encoded token kid is consistent

Comment: The keys that are accessed via the URL each have a kid (key id). A kid is also specified in the token. Have you checked whether one of the keys found at the URL has the kid specified in the token? Maybe not, which would explain the error message (as the key specified in the token would then not be found).

Comment: @Topaco - yes I've checked the kid in the jwks_uri against the kid specified in the token and they're different. but I'm unsure why

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question reliably as you have not said anything specific about the use case (where URL and tokens come from, what is actually to be achieved etc.). In any case, the code seems to work as such.